# ASP.NET MVC : Context type not found in assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

This is my first **asp.net mvc** project. I used **EF code first** approach and created a **separate class library** to write my model and context. I also referenced the class library in mvc project. 
But now after creating few more new models when I try to enable migration, it gives me an error. 
I also tried all the possible solutions mentioned here : [No context type found in the assembly. ASP.NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475998/no-context-type-found-in-the-assembly-asp-net-mvc4)

Still problem remains the same.
Am I missing something?

[image: Migration Error]
This is code for Context Class:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using FYPPharmAssistant.Domain.Models;


namespace FYPPharmAssistant.Domain.DAL
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext()
            : base("MyConnectionString")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<GenericName> GenericNames { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentStatus> PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

        //avoids pluralizing table names
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

And my **web.config**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=AVISHEKH\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog= FYPPharmAssistant; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <!--
    <contexts>
      <context type="FYPPharmAssistant.Domain.DAL.MyContext, FYPPharmAssistant">
        <databaseInitializer type="FYPPharmAssistant.Domain.DAL.PharmacyInitializer, FYPPharmAssistant" />
      </context>
    </contexts> -->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try changing the name="MyConnectionString" to name="MyContext" in your web.config?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it din't solve the problem.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/89xplq are you executing the migration enable on the right project?

btw by the message displayed in the second try i think the correct way to do that would be enable-migrations -ContextTypeName Domain.Dal.MyContext

Comment: the web.config belongs to `FYPPharmAssistant` project?

Comment: Taher Rahgooy . Thanks man ! You indirectly hit the point !! Yes, web.config belongs to FYPPharmAssistant. But all my entities is in another class library(FYPPrharmacyAssistant.Domain). I just changed the Default Project to FYPPrharmacyAssistant.Domain from the dropdown list in PackageManager Console and It worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This might be helpful for someone in future. So I am writing it again.**

> I just **changed the Default Project** to FYPPharmacyAssistant.Domain
> from the **dropdown list in PackageManager Console** and the problem
> is solved.  FYPPharmacyAssistant.Domain is my seperate project or
> class library consisting of all my entities and database context
> class.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Context needs to be in the same project as your migration configuration

Comment: Please be more specific.  Include specific recommendation on what code to change.